# How to connect to Wifi programmatically without remembering password?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, wifi

I can connect to Wifi with this code:

```
fun connectToWifi(ssid: String, password: String) {
    val wifiConfig = WifiConfiguration()
    wifiConfig.SSID = String.format("\"%s\"", ssid)
    wifiConfig.preSharedKey = String.format("\"%s\"", password)
    val wifiManager = applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE) as WifiManager
    val netId = wifiManager.addNetwork(wifiConfig)
    wifiManager.disconnect()
    wifiManager.enableNetwork(netId, true)
    AccessPointManager.currentlyConnectedNetId = netId
    wifiManager.reconnect()
}
```

But, it remembers password and auto reconnects even when app is killed. I need it to connect only once and forget the password. How can I achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may remove it from saved networks after app is killed. When app is not killed, listen for network changes and remove it when the network is disconnected.

```
List<WifiConfiguration> networks = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
for( WifiConfiguration wifi : networks) {
    wifiManager.removeNetwork(wifi.networkId);
    wifiManager.saveConfiguration();  
}
```

Comment: Thank you but it will still try to connect to same network again if user deosn't kill the app via task manager. While connecting to a network via settings, there is an option to remember or not. Isn't there an option for this in code?

Comment: i didn't understand the problem, when you want to forget the wifi credentials?

Comment: I want it to never remember credentials. It should only connect.

Comment: I think it is a system feature and cannot be prevent. However like i said, you can forget that wifi anytime you want. @Salih

Comment: Oh okay it looks like so. Thank you very much :)